# differential equation $(f(x)-2x)f'(x)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$f: R \to R$ is differential function. i think $(f(x)-2x)f'(x)=0$ means $f(x)=2x$ for all $x \in R$ or $f'(x)=0$ for all $x \in R$. Furthermore, i think if $g: R \to R$ is differential function and $g'(x)\neq 0$, $(f(x)-g(x))f'(x)=0$ means $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x \in R$ or $f'(x)=0$ for all $x \in R$. 
Is it true? how can i prove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if the proof is correct.
Let $A_0 =\{ x ~|~ g'(x)=0\}$. And $A_0 \neq \emptyset , A_0 \neq R $.
If there exist $x \in A_0$ such that $\exists (x_n) \subset R/A_0 ~s.t. ~ lim_{n \to \infty   }x_n=x$, then $g(x)=lim_{n \to \infty }g(x_n)=2x$. So $lim_{n \to \infty } \frac {g(x_n)-g(x)} {x_n -x}=2$, and $g'(x)$ exist, so $g'(x)=2$. it is contradiction.
therefore, $\forall x \in A_0, \exists \delta >0 s.t. (x-\delta, x+\delta) \subset A_0$.
because $A_0 \neq \emptyset , A_0 \neq R $. so there exist $x_0 \in A_0$, and WLOG there exist $y_0  \in R/A_0 s.t. y_0 > x_0$. Let $X=\{y~|~ y>x_0, \forall z \in (x_0, y], z \in A_0 \}$. then, $X \neq \emptyset $, $y_0 \notin A$ so $X$ is upper bounded. Let $Sup~ X=x_1$, then $x_1 >x_0$, $\forall x \in (x_0, x_1), x\in A_0$, and there exist $(x_n) \subset R/A_0 ~s.t. ~lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=x_1$, So $g(x_1)=2x_1, g'(x_1)=2$, but $g$ is continous at $[x_0, x_1]$, and $\forall x \in (x_0, x_1), g'(x)=0$. so $g(x)$ is constant function at $ [x_0, x_1]$. it is contradiction to $g'(x_1)=2$

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that $f\in C^1$ and let $A_0 := \{x\in \mathbb R : f'(x)=0\}$. Since $f'$ is continuous $A_0$ is a closed set.

Claim: It is either $A_0= \emptyset$ or $A_0 = \mathbb R$.

Proof:
Suppose neither is true, and let $x\in A_0$ and $y\in A_0^c = \mathbb R\setminus A_0$. W.l.o.g. we can assume that $x<y$, the other case $x>y$ can be done similarly. Let $x_0 = \sup\{t : y>t>x, t\in A_0\}$ and $(x_n)\subset A_0$ be a sequence with $\lim_n x_n = x_0$.
Since $A_0$ is closed, there exists $z>x_0$, s.t. $f'(t)\neq 0 $ for any $t\in(x_0,z)=:I$. Let $(y_n) \subset I$ s.t. $\lim_n y_n = x_0$. Note that since $f'(t)\neq 0$ for any $t\in I$, $f(t)=2t$ has to hold, hence $f'(t)=2$ for any $t\in I$, therefore
$$0 = \lim_n 0 = \lim_n f'(x_n) = f'(x_0) = \lim_n f'(y_n) =\lim_n2 =2 > 0 $$
due to the continuity of $f'$ and this is a contradiction. $ \Box $

If f is just continuous and differentiable, but the derivative is not necessarily continuous things get more challenging. Are you interested in that case as well?

Comment: why $x_0$ is well defined? is it upper bounded?

Comment: Forgot to add $t<y$, corrected it.